# mi proyecto de next.js no se ejecuta en el localhost

Tags: next.js

Es un login que contiene next-auth. La primera vez que ejecuté el código, localhost respondió con la página principal de next.js.

Hice algunos cambios y cuando actualicé la página no volvió a cargar el host local

Uso el comando npm run dev y no me da ningún resultado, intenté crear el mismo proyecto desde otra PC y me pasa lo mismo, no carga la página del host local

Espero que me puedan ayudar, no se que puede ser, soy nueva en esto del desarrollo, cualquier cosa es de ayuda):

esto es lo que me sale en el terminal cuando ejecuto npm run dev, intente eliminar la carpeta .next como vi en otras soluciones con esos comandos y me sale este error

y la otra imagen es como me sale cuando intento acceder al local host

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola katherine, bienvenida, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!... para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo agregues como texto.

Comment: Agrega los logs de error